# How to set BeanShellPostProcessor script from java code instead from Jmeter GUI?

Tags: jmeter

I have requirement, where I need to add `BeanShellPostProcessor` programmatically preferably in java.

Below is the sample code to add `BeanShellPostProcessor` to `JMX` and it is working.But I don't want to hard code the script (see the below code), script will change for each API test.
How to write the `beanshell` script programmatically

```
String script = "if (prev.getResponseCode().equals(401) == true) { prev.setResponseOK();}";

        BeanShellPostProcessor bspp = new BeanShellPostProcessor();
        bspp.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, BeanShellPostProcessor.class.getName());
        bspp.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
        bspp.setName("BeanShell PostProcessor");
        bspp.setProperty("resetInterpreter", false);
        bspp.setProperty("enabled", true);
        bspp.setProperty("script", script );

        HTTPSampleProxyHashTree.add(bspp);
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be dynamic?

Comment: Is there any built methods to create sample compare scripts.

Comment: or can we access beanshell predefined variables in our java code.Here I am declaring  'prev.getResponseCode()' in string. Can it be done using beanshell methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead.
2. You can make your script dynamic by loading it from i.e. [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html). The relevant code would be something like:

   ```
   String script = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("my.script",
           "if (prev.getResponseCode().equals(401) == true) { prev.setResponseOK();}");
   JSR223PostProcessor jsr223PostProcessor = new JSR223PostProcessor();
   jsr223PostProcessor.setName("JSR223 PostProcessor");
   jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("cacheKey", "true");
   jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("script", script);
   jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("scriptLanguage", "groovy");
   jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSR223PostProcessor.class.getName());
   jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
   ```

   if `my.script` property is set - JMeter will use its value as the Groovy script, if not - it will proceed with the default hard-coded value
3. You don't even need scripting at all, it would be enough to add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with `Ignore Status` box ticked.
4. Full code of the class which adds a JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
   import org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
   import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
   import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
   import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

   import java.io.FileOutputStream;

   public class JMeterFromScratch {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           String jmeterHome = "/path/to/your/jmeter/installation";
           StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

           //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
           JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
           JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
           JMeterUtils.initLocale();

           // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
           HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

           // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree

           // Create JSR223 PostProcessor
           String script = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("my.script",
                   "if (prev.getResponseCode().equals(401) == true) { prev.setResponseOK();}");
           JSR223PostProcessor jsr223PostProcessor = new JSR223PostProcessor();
           jsr223PostProcessor.setName("JSR223 PostProcessor");
           jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("cacheKey", "true");
           jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("script", script);
           jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty("scriptLanguage", "groovy");
           jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSR223PostProcessor.class.getName());
           jsr223PostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());

           // HTTP Sampler - open example.com
           HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
           examplecomSampler.setDomain("example.com.com");
           examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
           examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
           examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
           examplecomSampler.setName("Open example.com");
           examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
           examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


           // Loop Controller
           LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
           loopController.setLoops(1);
           loopController.setFirst(true);
           loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
           loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
           loopController.initialize();

           // Thread Group
           ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
           threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
           threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
           threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
           threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
           threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
           threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

           // Test Plan
           TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
           testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
           testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
           testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

           // HTTP Request Sampler and JSR223 PostProcessor
           HashTree blazeMeterSamplerTree = new HashTree();
           blazeMeterSamplerTree.add(examplecomSampler, jsr223PostProcessor);

           // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
           testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
           HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
           threadGroupHashTree.add(blazeMeterSamplerTree);

           SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jmx"));

           //Add Summarizer output
           Summariser summer = null;
           String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
           if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
               summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
           }

           // Store Execution Results into a .csv file
           String csvFile = jmeterHome + "/bin/result.csv";
           ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
           logger.setFilename(csvFile);
           testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

           //Run Test Plan
           jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
           jmeter.run();

           System.exit(0);

       }
   }
   ```
5. More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.I am using Response Assertion. Now I dont need to write any script , instead I am using built in methods from ResponseAssertion class.